# Linux, Using hardware interrupts on I/O to place data into user accessable area via Direct memory access

Tags: c, linux, io, beagleboneblack, interrupt-handling

I am currently working with the BeagleBone Black using Ubuntu and I am trying to find some direction. I have created a c program that listens for SIGIO and runs a *read()* to get the data on that line. From my research on the internet and looking through some books, it appears that this method is not very efficient in that using a loop listening for a Signal interrupt is bad because of the large amount of context switching (it should be noted that this I/O line will be busy so the SIGIO will trigger at least 4 times a second and this is an asynchronous). It was suggested to use hardware interrupts and have that trigger a response to take the data from the line and place it into a register and will be accessable from the User using Direct Memory Access preferably. So the question remains to be where can I look to get more info on how to do this, I find a lot of info on this topic but most of which just talk about how to OS does interrupts or using Signals, which with a busy line is pretty taxing.

Comment: Voted to close as "asking for external resource". Formally that is correct, but actually your question is far too broad. You have to do a lot more basic research how Linux works, about hardware, drivers, privileged accesses, concurrency, etc. before you even have an idea of how broad it is. No offence, but a strong request to learn and do research on your own first.

Comment: I appreciate your forwardness on pushing people to learn about the topic themselves first. But  I have researched it quite a bit, but everything i find is theory. I can't find actual examples of code where peole have been able to use hardware interrupts and  then proceed to use DMA to push data to other places.

Comment: " I can't find actual examples of code ..." . Sorry, but that just can't be! Linux is open source and all sources are available for free. You really want to tell there is not a single driver in the kernel sources which uses interrupts and DMA??

Answer (score 0):

If you are that much concerned about the timings and latency, you should probably use some real time system.

Fortunately, Beaglebone black has real-time processing cores on its SOC, called the PRU (Programmable real-time units). 
If you are new to the concept of PRUs, you probably would like to start [here](https://www.zeekhuge.me/post/working_with_prus_beagleboneblack_introduction_to_prus/) and then, once you have understood the need and purpose of the PRUs, that same website has some tutorial to get started.

With the latest software support like remoteproc, rpmsg and [Beaglescope project](https://github.com/ZeekHuge/BeagleScope), PRUs can be used quite easily, once you have understood its working.